# Target Unreachable, identifier ''loginBean'' resolved to null

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, java-8

I try make a simple example with login in the JSF. I use java-8.

While I try login, recieve:

**/index.xhtml @13,80 value="#{loginBean.userName}": JBWEB006016: Target Unreachable, identifier ''loginBean'' resolved to null**

I have the impression that, this is connected with lambda expression. When I delete line with stream, the problem is solved.

Best regards,

Adrian

index.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="notLogged" rendered="#{!loginBean.isLogged()}">
        <h:form id="loginForm">
            Login: <h:inputText id="login" value="#{loginBean.userName}" /><br />
            Password: <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginBean.userPassword}" /><br />

            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login()}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="logged" rendered="#{loginBean.isLogged()}">
        Hi, <h:outputText value="#{loginBean.whoIsLogged()}" />!

        <h:commandButton value="Logout" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
```

LoginBean.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    private static final String SESSION_NAME = "user";
    private final List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User("test1", "test1"), new User("test2", "test2"));

    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;

    public void login() {
        if (users.stream().filter(u -> u.getLogin().equals(userName) && u.getPassword().equals(userPassword)).count() > 0) {
            this.getSession().setAttribute(SESSION_NAME, userName);
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Wrong!"));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        this.getSession().invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isLogged() {
        return this.getSession() != null && this.getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_NAME) != null;
    }

    public String whoIsLogged() {
        return this.getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_NAME).toString();
    }

    private HttpSession getSession() {
        return (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
public class User {
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public User(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your LoginBean class have the @ManagedBean attribute?

Comment: Sorry, that was copy-paste mistake, I fixed this

Comment: Confirm you're importing the annotations from the right package. JSE-8 is not relevant here; it's your version of JavaEE (read: your app server) that's important

Comment: I use javax.faces.bean.*